# Kubuntu 18.10 doesn't remember dual display settings after reboot (desktop computer)

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors

I have 2 displays on my desktop, connected to my Radeon Vega 64, and just installed Kubuntu 18.10.

Both are correctly identified and extended (not cloned), but the changes that I need are: 90 degree rotation on one of them, and switch the primary panel to be the other one. I can correctly perform these changes. But upon reboot, these changes are forgotten and rotation is reset on my rotated panel, and the primary panel is reset to the one I don't want.

What can I do about this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I "solved" this by going back to Kubuntu 18.04.1, monitor configuration is correctly remembered, and also I'm not getting the random deep freezes I was getting on 18.10 (happened ~10 times in 2 days). Forgot to mention my hardware, in case the problems I mentioned are caused by some driver regression: Ryzen 7 1800X, Radeon Vega 64.

Answer (score 1):

Have you, you know, considered reporting this issue to Ubuntu, instead of posting a question to AskUbuntu? I'll report it first, and you're welcome to tick the "I have this problem too!" link on it. I can't comment on my own answer here, of course, because I don't have the requisite 50 reputation to comment on anything. I can, however, post random answers and hope that earns me reputation.

I have the problem as well, and I was going to report it anyway. I don't really have an option to back down to 18.04.1, since it has an older kernel, and I need the 4.18 or better kernel, and would rather not deal with at least weekly kernel updates from mainline.

Also, I can answer your problems with deep freezes. It has to do with your Ryzen CPU, and possibly which motherboard you have. The only known solution is to disable C6 sleep states, as the combination of Ryzen 1xxx/2xxx, certain motherboards, and power supplies, is that C6 state drops the voltage so low that it eventually hits 0 volts and the CPU locks up completely. Presumably, Windows has the same damn workaround, but I guess most Linux distributions just don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Oh look, a bug report. Please kindly vote on it. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plasma-desktop/+bug/1806543

Comment: Cool, good that you made that report, I'll vote on it. I asked here because I thought it's inconceivable that Canonical hasn't tested dual monitor configuration, and surely it must be something I'm doing wrong. Also, it's weird that I had the freezes in 18.10 but not in 18.04.1.